# How to define a python string (quasi-)constant that has dynamic inputs?

Tags: python, string, constants

For example:

```
MY_MESSAGE = 'Dear %s, hello.'
# ...
name = "jj"
print MY_MESSAGE % name
```

Does python have a feature for accomplishing something like my above code?

Comment: Have you actually tried it? That code is perfectly valid.

Comment: wow. someone needs some sleep

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the exact way you wrote it. Your code is fine.

Comment: I'd delete this bad girl, but probably best to leave me with a mark of shame! Thanks for the quick response :)

Comment: @dolan, I admire you leaving your stain. :) Get some sleep!

Answer (score 3):

Python does not really have the same concept of "constant" that you will find in C. So what you have there is a fairly good approach.

I would actually argue that this is one example of "we're all consenting adults" does not hold up terribly well. Think the language is awesome, but a constant every now and again would be... nice.

Comment: It is quite nice how Ruby does it: throws a warning if you redefine _any_ variable that starts with a capital letter.

Answer (score 2):

The string formatting operator: % can also do other neat things:

```
STRING = "This is %(foo)s, and this is also %(foo)s"
print STRING % {"foo": "BAR"}

# => This is BAR, and this is also BAR
```

This is really useful if you will be repeating one argument. Sure beats

```
FORMAT_STRING % ("BAR", "BAR")
```

You can also do padding, and number formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, but I believe there is a more preferred way to do that:

```
>>> my_message = 'Dear {:s}, hello.'
>>> my_message.format('jj')
'Dear jj, hello.'
```

Preferred, because of possible future replacement of `%` operator by `.format()` method.

As mentioned in Mark Lutz's *Learning Python. Fourth Edition*, `format` method:

> - has a few features not found in the `%` expression,
> - can make substitution values more explicit,
> - trades an operator for arguably more mnemonic method name,
> - does not support different syntax for single and multiple
>     substitution value cases,

and later, in the same book:

> ... there is some risk that Python developers may deprecate the `%` expression in favor of the `format` method in the future. In fact, there is a note to that effect in Python 3.0's manuals.

Comment: .format() definitely has its place, but % is not going to be deprecated -- there are too many who still use it, and will keep on using it.

Comment: @Ethan Furman: Probably you are right, but `%` has many disadvantages and `.format()` has been created to replace it (at least it looks like, when you look at [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)).